# window.location not refreshing to the existing URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP page with implementation of jQuery horizontal tabs. I have added a jQuery script so that the page URL reflects the tab#. I have a form on the page and upon form submission I need to refresh and stay on this same page to include the jQuery correct tab number.

This is the code to add the jQuery tab number to the URL:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    $("<p>").html("Loaded at " + new Date()).appendTo(
        document.body
    );
    showTab(location.hash || "#tabs-1");

    $("#nav a").click(function() {
        var hash = this.getAttribute("href");
        if (hash.substring(0, 1) === "#") {
            hash = hash.substring(1);
        }
        location.hash = hash;
        showTab(hash);
        return false;
    });

    function showTab(hash) {
        $("div.tab").hide();
        $("#tab-" + hash).show();
    }

});

</script>
```

The full URL of the page is http://somedomain.com/includes/nonadmin_user_profile.php#tabs-5 and includes the tab number for the jQuery horizontal tab.

I am using this script to refresh and stay on the same page: `echo "<script>window.location=window.location</script>";`

On refresh here is the problem as it lands at this URL which does not include the tab number. http://somedomain.com/includes/nonadmin_user_profile.php

Any suggestions would be appreciated very much.

Here is another detail: The problem described above does not occur if I merely refresh the page with the browser refresh button or if I right click the page and refresh. In this instance the page refreshes and stays on the full url with the tab#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Disaster Faster's request, the issue encountered was simply that the browser was not going to the desired location of the page. The form data was successfully submitted and correct page was loaded.

The solution to his issue was modifying the `form`'s `action` attribute to include the location information (similar to adding location information to an anchor).

Original:

```
<form action="nonadmin_user_profile.php" method="post">
```

New:

```
<form action="nonadmin_user_profile.php#tabs-5" method="post">
```

**Original Post:**

The `window.location = window.location` redirect should include the location information.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6dqcmh9d/

If you click the button first, it'll report the URL with the location information because it hasn't been added to the URL. Then click the link and re-click the button. You'll receive the URL with the location information added.

If you want just the location information, you can use `window.location.hash`, but this will only produce the location on the page, not the URL of the page.

The problem you'll run into will be with the form submission. To submit a form without changing the page, you'll either have to submit the form to a new window (add `target="_blank"` to the form) or implement AJAX. In either case, we'd need a little more of your code to help with integrating it properly.

Comment: @DisasterFaster That hashtag didn't save in the redirect, or the form didn't submit?

Comment: AoN the form submitted just fine. But where I am on page http://somedomain.com/includes/nonadmin_user_profile.php#tabs-5 at form submit after refresh I land at http://somedomain.com/includes/nonadmin_user_profile.php and this is after trying every suggestion here. I am baffled and wonder if the javascript that adds the tab number is the culprit?

Comment: @DisasterFaster My guess is that the form is submitting instead of the JavaScript triggering. Forms, by default, submit unto themselves, but the submission does not retain location information. What you're asking it to do is submit the form without actually submitting it (if that makes any sense). Normally, for this, you'd use JavaScript to catch the submission and prevent default action to instead have your own performed. We need more of the code to help you troubleshoot. Also, I've modified the answer a bit.

Comment: AoN this is like 2300+ lines of code so I would prefer to spare you the hardship lol. I do have an idea though and would love your feedback. While the URL is showing somedomain.com/includes/nonadmin_user_profile.php#tabs-5 and after I submit I land at somedomain.com/includes/nonadmin_user_profile.php now could this be simply because my form has the action as "nonadmin_user_profile.php" and that's why I land like I do because of the form action does not include the #tabs-5?

Comment: @DisasterFaster That would definitely do it. Though I can't say I ever tried submitting a form with location information tacked onto the target action, it stands to reason that it should work. When a form is submitted, that data is submitted to the target action and the page is redirected to that location. It the target action contains location information, it stands to reason that the browser would render it the same as if it had been an anchor with the same target. Give adding the location information a try, it couldn't hurt.

Comment: Yes! AoN I changed the form action to "nonadmin_user_profile.php#tabs-5" and it works beautiful now. Thank you for all your input! Could you edit your answer so I can mark this as solved?

Comment: @DisasterFaster Per your request, I have update my response. You may wish to consider updating your question to better describe the actual issue you were encountering to ensure others with the problem do not mistake it for a different issue. ^^

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the tab controls are being handled with `onclick` events or something similar, and are not listening for hash changes `onload`. You'll likely need to add some custom JS to force the tab change if there's a hash change.

What's wrong with using the [`reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) method?

```
document.location.reload(true);
```

From the docs:

> The `Location.reload()` method Reloads the resource from the current
>   URL. Its optional unique parameter is a `Boolean`, which, when it is
>   true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is
>   false or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its
>   cache.

If you need to integrate it into a PHP `echo` struct, use:

```
echo '<script>document.location.reload(true);</script>';
```

Comment: You didn't explain the problem.

Comment: Thank you BenM. I tried your example and still have the same result as described in my original post and also I noticed that the updated data was not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reload()` to refresh the page, eg:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Or given your example:

```
echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you Rory. I tried your example and still have the same result as described in my original post.

Comment: You didn't explain the problem.